# Vogels err: Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vogels

I have one line in my file: `const vogels = require('vogels');`
 however whenever I try to run the file I get the following error:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/neilshweky/Dropbox/School 2018-2019/NETS 212/VMF_Shared_Folder/G48/node_modules/bunyan/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:17:23)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
    { Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/neilshweky/Dropbox/School 2018-2019/NETS 212/VMF_Shared_Folder/G48/node_modules/bunyan/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:17:23)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
    { Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/neilshweky/Dropbox/School 2018-2019/NETS 212/VMF_Shared_Folder/G48/node_modules/bunyan/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:17:23)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Here is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "MY_URL"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.358.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "dtrace-provider": "^0.8.7",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lru-cache": "^4.1.3",
    "vogels": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why this error is happening, as all I'm doing is requiring a package which I downloaded (via npm install). I've looked through most everything I can find but found no answers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I just ignored the error and the package works fine!